# How to check if given ocject is an instance of "code" generated with compile builtin?

Tags: python

When I compile a string and ask for its type:

```
c = compile("5", filename="five", mode="eval")
type(c)
```

...i get `code`
However, I cannot simply verify whether the type of the object is `code` or not:

```
isinstance(c,code)
NameError: name 'code' is not defined
```

How can I perform this type of test reliably?

Comment: is `code` a class? If not, define a class with name `code`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [`types.CodeType`](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/types.html#types.CodeType):

```py
import types

c = compile("5", filename="five", mode="eval")
print(isinstance(c,types.CodeType)) # True
```